# Can't force IPv6 on my network

Tags: ios, macos, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to test my app on an IPv6 network following an app rejection from apple. [I've followed the instructions provided on this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) to set up an IPv6 network, however when I go to a site like http://www.useipv6.com it still says I'm using IPV4.

It seems my local IP address is IPv6, but my public one is still IPv4.

Is there a way I can force it to use IPv6 always? or is this the expected behaviour? I can't seem to replicate the problems apple is facing so I'm worried that maybe it's not an ipv6 issue at all and I'm on a wild goose chase, but want to be sure.

Comment: "It seems my local IP address is IPv6, but my public one is still IPv4. " That's fine. That's what you're supposed to test with.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, I had to go into my network settings, click Advanced... and then set the "Configure IPv4" dropdown to Off (it was set to Using DHCP). This forces it to use only the IPv6 address.